# Spark 1.3.0: Building Examples: Failed to execute goal org.scalastyle

Tags: maven, build, apache-spark

After building Spark 1.3.0 in the root directory, no matter what command to build `examples` directory:

```
 mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

or just:

```
 mvn -DskipTest clean package
```

I get:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scalastyle:scalastyle-maven-plugin:0.4.0:check (default) on project spark-examples_2.10: Failed during w: Unable to find configuration file at location scalastyle-config.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Answer (score 6):

copy the  **[spark_root]/scalastyle-config.xml** to **[spark_root]/examples/scalastyle-config.xml** can solve the problem

Comment: The same is explained here too. this answer works. https://www.codesd.com/item/spark-1-3-0-building-examples-can-not-run-org-scalastyle-lens.html

Answer (score 4):

Copying `scalastyle-config.xml` into the `examples` folder from parent folder should solve the issue.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalastyle</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalastyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
...
  <configLocation>scalastyle-config.xml</configLocation>
```

The configuration in `pom.xml` expects the configuration file in the directory maven is invoked from.

Comment: this is a bit weird because this plugin is not present on the pom.xml file of /examples, maybe it is already in master pom.xml? anyway, copying that file into examples folder resolves the issue.